# navigate to flipview

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uianimation

i used below code for infolight button (Thanks to   https://stackoverflow.com/users/630145/ankit-bhardwaj)

```
// This will create ur info button in center.
    UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    UIBarButtonItem *infoButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];
    [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToRechercherView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    toolBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleLeft,infoButtonItem,flexibleLeft, nil];
```

and this for animation & i get the part that how it flips but it flips to same page.

```
//This is for swipe animation. add your view inside.
-(void)goToRechercherView{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                           forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

So i have added flipviewcontroller.h .m .xib file to project and i want to open that xib/page in flipanimation.

some one suggest me method for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the new view controller flipping from right instead of left during presentation, I recommend you present the new controller modally. It's as easy as:

```
UIViewController *mySecondViewController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someID"];
[mySecondViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentViewController:mySecondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code May be helpfull for you

```
-(void)goToRechercherView{

      RechercherView *info3 = [[RechercherView alloc]initWithNibName:@"RechercherView" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController * nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:info3];

        info3.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nvc animated:YES];

//  if you using latest Version of iOS Just Change the following

  [self.navigationController presentViewController:nvc animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this...

First one is......

```
newView setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 480.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)]; //notice this is OFF screen!
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
[newView setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)]; //notice this is ON screen!
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Second option is to use built in animations as flip and curl:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                           forView:newView
                            cache:YES];

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:settingsView.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```